# Looking for Sri Kalki's stotram to Lord Shiva in Sanskrit

Tags: shiva, identification-request, kalki, stotra, kalki-purana

According to the [Kalki Purana](http://www.astrojyoti.com/kalkipurana.htm), Sri Kalki will obtain the horse and his sword by propitiating Lord Shiva.

> After offering His respectful obeisances to Lord Siva, who is very
>   easily pleased, and worshiping him with devotion, Lord Kalki began to
>   speak, keeping His mind fully under control.

Then Sri Kalki recites a Lord Shiva Stotram (It is found in the Purana's 2nd chapter).

The English translation of the Stotram is as follows:

> Text 14
>
> Lord Kalki said: О Lord Sankara, you are the oldest of all, the
>   husband of Gauri, the lord of the universe, the only protector of the
>   living entities, and the shelter of everyone. Your neck is decorated
>   with the serpent, Vasuki, you have three eyes and five heads, you are
>   always absorbed in transcendental ecstasy, and you award liberation to
>   your devotees I offer my obeisances unto you.
>
> Text 15
>
> You are the lord of mystic yoga and the destroyer of lusty desires.
>   Your form is fearful to behold, your head is always wet with the water
>   of the Ganges, the matted hair on your head looks most enchanting,
>   your forehead is decorated with a mark of the half moon, and you are
>   the personification of maha-kala. I offer my obeisances unto you.
>
> Texts 16-17
>
> You frequent crematoriums in the company of ghosts and hobgoblins, and
>   you carry a trident and other weapons in your Hands at the time of
>   annihilation, the entire creation is burnt to ashes by the blazing
>   fire emanating from your anger. The conditioned souls are born in this
>   world under the influence of false ego, and their bodies are made of
>   the five gross material elements. You are the lord of the mode of
>   ignorance, and thus you are one of the directors of the material
>   universe. Although you are involved in universal affairs, you always
>   remain aloof from material association as you remain absorbed in
>   transcendental ecstasy, I offer my obeisances unto you.
>
> Text18
>
> I worship Lord Siva, the protector of the universe and the Super soul of
>   all living entities. He is always victorious, being a qualitative
>   incarnation of Lord Visnu, and He delivers saintly persons by
>   protecting the principles of religion. He is the personification of
>   transcendental sound, a reservoir of divine qualities, and the
>   possessor of great intelligence.
>
> Text19
>
> By your order the wind blows, fire burns, the sun distributes heat and
>   light, and the moon, planets and stars illuminate the sky. I offer my
>   obeisances unto you.
>
> Text20
>
> By your order, the earth sustains all moving and nonmoving entities,
>   Indra showers rain, the time factor divides the duties of everyone, and
>   Mount Sumeru, which is the shelter of the universe, remains fixed
>   at the center I offer my humble obeisances to the universal form of
>   Lord Siva.[**the Stotram ends here**]
>
> Text21
>
> After hearing these prayers, Lord Siva, being omniscient, appeared
>   before Lord Kalki with Parvati and spoke to Him while smiling grandly.

...............................

The Phalasruti of this Stotram, as given by Lord Shiva, is as follows:

> Anyone on this earth who faithfully hears the glorious prayers that
>   you have offered me will achieve all kinds of perfection, both in this
>   life and in the next.
>
> Text 24
>
> If a student recites these prayers, his education will become
>   fruitful, if a pious person recites these prayers, he will attain
>   pious merit, and if a sense enjoyer recites these prayers, he will
>   enjoy all kinds of sense gratification. Anyone who recites or hears
>   these prayers will have all his desires fulfilled.

.............

And, thereafter Sri Kalki will receive the horse and the sword as described in the following verses:

> I would also like to present You this sharp, strong sword and so
>   please accept it. The Handle of this sword is bedecked with jewels,
>   and it is extremely powerful. As such, this sword will help You to
>   reduce the heavy burden of the earth.
>
> Text 28
>
> After hearing all this, Lord Kalki offered His obeisances and then
>   departed for the village of Sambhala, riding on the back of the horse
>   given by Lord Siva.

.....................

**I am looking for this Stotram in Sanskrit so that it can be recited.**

Comment: I could find it in the _third_ chapter (page 22) here:https://vedpuran.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/kalkipuranhindi1.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Chapter 3 of Kalki Purana** (unabridged version) has this sloka. Here is complete sloka (from verse 14 to verse 20) in Devanagari and IAST.

Sanskrit verses taken from [here](https://archive.org/stream/KalkiPuranaSanskrit1890/Kalki%20Purana%20Sanskrit%201890#page/n15/mode/2up). You can also read complete Kalki Purana in Sanskrit and English from [here](https://archive.org/details/KalkiPuranaBumipatiDasISKON) (translated by Bhumipati Das).

> कल्कि रुवाच । 
>   kalki ruvāca ।
>
> गौरीनाथ विश्वनाथ शरण्यं भूतावासं वासुकीकण्ठभूषम्। 
>  त्र्यक्षं
>   पञ्चास्यादिदेवं पुराणं वन्दे सान्द्रानन्दसन्दोहदक्षम् ॥१४॥
>
> gaurīnātha viśvanātha śaraṇyaṃ bhūtāvāsaṃ vāsukīkaṇṭhabhūṣam। 
>   tryakṣaṃ pañcāsyādidevaṃ purāṇaṃ vande sāndrānandasandohadakṣam ॥14॥
>
> योगाधीशं कामनाशं करालं गङ्गासङ्गक्लिन्नमूर्द्धानमीशम् ।  
>  
>   जटाजूटाटोपरिक्षिप्तभावं महाकालं चन्द्रभालं नमामि॥१.५॥
>
> yogādhīśaṃ kāmanāśaṃ karālaṃ gaṅgāsaṅgaklinnamūrddhānamīśam ।  
>  
>   jaṭājūṭāṭoparikṣiptabhāvaṃ mahākālaṃ candrabhālaṃ namāmi॥1.5॥
>
> श्मशानस्थं भूतवेतालसङ्ग नानाशास्त्रै: खड्गशूलादिभिश्च  । 
>   व्यग्रात्युग्रा बाहुबो। लोकनाशे यस्य क्रोधोद्वतलोकोऽस्तमेति१६
>
> śmaśānasthaṃ bhūtavetālasaṅga nānāśāstrai: khadgaśūlādibhidya । 
>   vyagrātyugrā bāhubo। lokanāśe yasya krodhodvataloko'stameti||  16||
>
> यो भूतादिः पञ्चभूतोः सिसृक्षुः तन्मात्रात्मा कालकर्मस्वभावैः। 
>   प्रहृत्येदं प्राप्य जीवत्वमिशो ब्रह्मानन्दो रमते तं नमामि ॥१७॥
>
> yo bhūtādiḥ pañcabhūtoḥ sisṛkṣuḥ tanmātrātmā kālakarmasvabhāvaiḥ। 
>   prahṛtyedaṃ prāpya jīvatvamiśo brahmānando ramate taṃ namāmi ॥17॥
>
> स्थितौ विष्णुः सर्वजिष्णुः सुरात्मा लोकान् साधून् धर्म्मसेतून्
>   बिभर्षि । 
>  ब्रह्माद्यांशे योऽभिमानी गुणात्मा शव्दाद्यङ्गैस्थं
>   परेशं नमामि ॥ १८ ॥
>
> sthitau viṣṇuḥ sarvajiṣṇuḥ surātmā lokān sādhūn dharmmasetūn bibharṣi
>   । 
>  brahmādyāṃśe yo'bhimānī guṇātmā śavdādyaṅgaisthaṃ pareśaṃ
>   namāmi ॥ 18 ॥
>
> यस्याज्ञया वायवो वान्ति लोके ज्वलत्यग्निः सविता याति तप्यन् शीतांशुः
>   खे तारकैः सग्रहैश्च प्रवर्त्तते तं परेशं प्रपद्ये ॥ १९ ॥
>
> yasyājñayā vāyavo vānti loke jvalatyagniḥ savitā yāti tapyan śītāṃśuḥ
>   khe tārakaiḥ sagrahaiśca pravarttate taṃ pareśaṃ prapadye ॥ 19 ॥
>
> यस्याश्खासात् सर्वधात्री धरित्री देवो वर्षत्यंभु कालः प्रमाता । 
>   मेरुर्मध्ये भुवनानाञ्च भर्त्तां तमीशानं विश्वरूपं नमामि ॥२०॥
>
> yasyāśkhāsāt sarvadhātrī dharitrī devo varṣatyaṃbhu kālaḥ pramātā ।
>   
>  merurmadhye bhuvanānāñca bharttāṃ tamīśānaṃ viśvarūpaṃ namāmi
>   ॥20॥

Comment: I have manually typed this sloka. Please feel free to notify any errors that might have crept into the sloka .

Comment: https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivastotrakalki.pdf                                                           Encoded from BrihatstotraratnAkara ( Kehav Bhikaji Dhavale Prakashan )